# Multithreads multiqueue..how can manage it?

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv

I have to create a program that's use threads to elaborate 10 images with OpenCV. For do this, I think that break the work in 3 threads, and use 4 queues to contain initial 10 images, and intermediate images during elaboration.

This is the diagram of what I have to do:

[image: Diagram of threads and data floyd]

Now, I think that for do this I can use std::queue to manage the queues, so pass to every thread an queue object. 
The problem is:

1) I have to create a class "queue" with the push, pop methods thread safe, right? With mutex variable to regolarize multithreading and syncronization...

2) Evey thread works on 2 queue: POP from one and PUSH to another one. So each thread is both consumer/producer...How do I pass to each thread the two object pointers of the queue class in the input and output? (there are two objects, so two pointers)?

With my code, second thread see input queue always EMPTY. Someone can help me? Give me an idea about this problem?

This is my code, that don't work with the two threads (second thread see input queue always empty:

```
 #include <opencv\cv.h>
 #include <opencv\highgui.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <windows.h>
 #include <process.h>
 #include <ctime>
 #include <queue>

 using namespace std;
 using namespace cv;


/* thread safe queue*/

template<typename T>
class coda_concorr
{
private:
    std::queue<T> la_coda;
    HANDLE mutex;
    public:
    bool complete;
    coda_concorr()
    {
        mutex = CreateMutex(NULL,FALSE,NULL);
        complete = false;
    }
    void push(T& data)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(mutex,INFINITE);
        la_coda.push(data);
        ReleaseMutex(mutex);
    }
    bool vuota() const
    {
        bool RetCode;
        WaitForSingleObject(mutex,INFINITE);
        RetCode= la_coda.empty();
        ReleaseMutex(mutex);
        return RetCode;
    }

    bool try_pop(T& popped)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(mutex,INFINITE);
        if (la_coda.empty())
        {
            ReleaseMutex(mutex);
            return false;
        }
        popped = la_coda.front();
        la_coda.pop();
        ReleaseMutex(mutex);
        return true;
    }
};

//packet passing to threads
struct Args
{
    coda_concorr<cv::Mat> in;
    coda_concorr<cv::Mat> out;
};

//grey decrease funct
void grey (void *param){
    Mat temp1,temp2;
    Args* arg = (Args*)param;
    if(!arg->in.vuota()){
    while(arg->in.try_pop(temp1)){
    cvtColor(temp1,temp2,CV_BGR2GRAY);
    arg->out.push(temp2);
        }
    arg->out.complete=true;
    }
    else{
        Sleep(100);
    }
    _endthread();
}
//threshold funct
void soglia(void *param){
    Mat temp1a,temp2a;
    Args* arg = (Args*)param;
    if(arg->in.vuota()){
    while(arg->in.vuota()){
            cout<<endl<<"Coda vuota"<<endl;
            Sleep(100);
        }
    }
    else{
        while(arg->in.try_pop(temp1a)){
        threshold(temp1a,temp2a,128,255,THRESH_BINARY);
        arg->out.push(temp2a);
            }
     }
     arg->out.complete=true;
    _endthread();
}
int main()
{
    coda_concorr<cv::Mat> ingresso;
    coda_concorr<cv::Mat> coda1;
    coda_concorr<cv::Mat> coda2;
    coda_concorr<cv::Mat> uscita;


    //in array
    Mat inn[10];
    Mat out;

    //assing images
    inn[0]=imread("C:/OPENCV/Test/imgtest/bird1.jpg",1);
    inn[1]=imread("C:/OPENCV/Test/imgtest/bird2.jpg",1);
    inn[2]=imread("C:/OPENCV/Test/imgtest/bird3.jpg",1);
    inn[3]=imread("C:/OPENCV/Test/imgtest/pig1.jpg",1);
    inn[4]=imread("C:/OPENCV/Test/imgtest/pig2.jpg",1);
    inn[5]=imread("C:/OPENCV/Test/imgtest/pig3.jpg",1);
    inn[6]=imread("C:/OPENCV/Test/imgtest/spider1.jpg",1);
    inn[7]=imread("C:/OPENCV/Test/imgtest/spider2.jpg",1);
    inn[8]=imread("C:/OPENCV/Test/imgtest/spider3.jpg",1);
    inn[9]=imread("C:/OPENCV/Test/imgtest/Nutella.jpg",1);



    Args dati,dati2;
    //populating queue 
    for(int i=0;i<=9;i++){
        dati.in.push(inn[i]);
    }
//assing second queue   
dati.out=coda1;

    HANDLE handle1,handle2;

    handle1 = (HANDLE) _beginthread(grey,0,&dati);

    //share part that don't WORK
    dati2.in=coda1;
    dati2.out=coda2;

    handle2 = (HANDLE) _beginthread(soglia,0,&dati2);



    WaitForSingleObject(handle2,INFINITE);
    WaitForSingleObject(handle1,INFINITE);



    //output
    while (dati2.out.try_pop(out)){
        imshow("immagine",out);
        waitKey(100);
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;

}
```

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Which threading library do you use ? What is you OS ?

Comment: If you're going to use a mutex/condition variable to guard access, you don't need to use your own queue instead of using std::queue.

Another option, that avoids the need for queues, is the concept of message passing using something like [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/)

Comment: ... or switch to a language that provides both an actor model and a wrapper to opencv ([Scala + Java OpenCV wrapper](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html)). The learning curve will be (very?) steep, but expect a lot of fun in the long time.

Comment: Thanks to all...I'm on Visual C++ 2010 and OpenCV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For point 1/, you indeed need some synchronization object, or use a message passing library, as suggested in the comments.

For point 2/, your multithreading library may provide you the ability to pass an argument to you thread function.

- Declare a small class that contains references to two queues, an *in* queue, an *out* queue.
- In your main, instantiate all the queues you need and an instance of the small class for each of your thread, passing them the *in* and *out* queues for every thread.
- Start your threads, passing the instances of the small class as the callback function argument. You now have acces to *in* and *out* queues from each of your threads.

**Edit (since you edited you question)**

```
bool vuota() const
{
    WaitForSingleObject(mutex,INFINITE);
    return la_coda.empty();
    ReleaseMutex(mutex);
}
```

is wrong.

```
bool vuota() const
{
    WaitForSingleObject(mutex,INFINITE);
    bool tmp = la_coda.empty();
    ReleaseMutex(mutex);
    return tmp;
}
```

The same happens in `bool try_pop(T& popped)`.
Check that your release your mutex before leaving the functions.

Comment: Thank you...then, the solution of make my own class queue it's correct (I mean what you call small class queue)..in the small class I have to declare only the reference to 2 queue like "public" variables, and a constructor for these two queues?

Comment: Pretty sure that's what M.R. is suggesting, yes.  I would probably go this way too.  Any other stuff you later find out you need to communicate to the threads can be stuffed in there as well, and it keeps the queues accessible to some 'monitor' activity that occasionally polls the queue counts and displays them for debug/optimizations efforts.

Comment: Yes, the queues can be `public` variables (references to some `queue`object), or can be `private` variables with accessors. Moreover, the _in_ `queue` may be declared as `const` to prevent unwanted modification of the input queue by the processing thread.

Comment: Ok, I'll try this solution...if I have others problem, post here my question! Thank you very much to all!!

Comment: I can't have competition...I have update question to show you my code...please help me...

Comment: `bool vuota() const` .... `return la_coda.empty(); ReleaseMutex(mutex);`. This is KO. `ReleaseMutex(mutex);` will never been called.

Comment: I have update code today...please, read it and let me know how can fix it.

Comment: You should ask another question with you updated code, describing exactly what does not work, what debugging actions you tried to do.

Answer (score 1):

If thread 2 waits for thread 1 to work, and thread 3 waits for thread 2, there is no point to having threads. One thread running all three functions is the best approach.

Now, you suppose that while thread 2 is processing the first image, T1 can process the second one. But...

In this scenario

- Threads 2 & 3 have to wait for the first image
- If any thread is constantly faster than the others, it will stall waiting for work.

The right approach here is to use only two queues (In/Out), and have multiple threads to analyze different images. So, T1, T2, .. Tn will take an image from IN, process it completely, then store the results in OUT.

It may be even possible to get rid of the results queue, and send them directly somewhere (a file, display, etc). Just make sure to synchronize the destination object.

Comment: This is an intriguing idea..in your opinion, have more threads but that each able to do all elaboration, it's best that have more threads that passing each others the image for elaborate it in steps? In term of execution time, the differences from two ideas, what are for you? Thanks for this other point of view...

Comment: This approach makes better use of the processor time (no thread is waiting for other thread to process, just for some input), and makes more sense overall. Moreover, it's simpler (having to handle 5 synchronized queues is a bit... tricky). You can use a semaphore on the input queue to signal a new (or more) input image(s).

Comment: I have updated question to show you my code and problem...please help me if you can